# Put Set of object to JSON

Tags: json, flutter

How can put a Set of object to Json. Seems like that code is not good at all

```
Future<File> writeBasket(Set<Item> listItems) async {

  final file = await _localFile;
  var jsonString = listItems.map((Item item) {
    return jsonEncode(item);
  });

  return file.writeAsString(jsonString.toString());
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer When the number of object is quite big, function  shortens  the resulting  string with “....”

Comment: That's unlikely. Perhaps only a "feature" from the console log to truncate the output. Better to investigate in the debugger of your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `Item` has a `toJson` method, for example:

```
class Item {
  String val1;

  Item(this.val1);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'val1': val1};
}
```

The nearest equivalent to a set in json is a list, so convert your set to a list before calling `json.encode`.

```
  Set<Item> items = Set<Item>()..add(Item('xxx'))..add(Item('yyy'));
  String j = json.encode(items.toList());
  print(j);
```

prints `[{"val1":"xxx"},{"val1":"yyy"}]` which you could save to your file.